# ecryptfs: what and where is the key represented by "fnek_sig"?

Tags: ecryptfs

I have encrypted private folder.
In mount options there are two sigs: `ecryptfs_fnek_sig` and `ecryptfs_sig`.
When I call `keyctl show` it shows, that I have two keys represented by these sigs. But actually I have only one key in my wrapped-passphrase file.
So my question is: where the second key comes from?

And additional question: what happens if I don't specify `fnek_sig` in mount options (provided I have file names encrypted)?

Answer (score 0):

the fnek key and its fnek_sig are generated automatically by ecryptfs, out of the passphrase you specified.
You can manually insert the two keys into the keyring with the command line " ecryptfs-add-passphrase --fnek" - this will ask to enter the passphrase -.
It will generate the main and fnek keys, insert them into the keyring and print the 2 signatures. The 2nd one is the fnek_sig.
Very usefull when you want to manually recover an ecrypted folder.